# Telegram: hide online status

Tags: privacy, telegram

Is there any way to hide the "Online" status on the Telegram application, and possible as well also the "Last seen" time stamp?

If this is not possible, is there a way to contact the developing team to ask them to include this feature? I haven't found like a forum or a place to put requests.

It seems weird that for an app that is supposed to be so privacy-centered, as opposed to Whatsapp, they have left in this really intrusive feature.

Comment: There is a 'contact the developer' link on every app in the Google Play store, just click on that and email them about it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, apart from the moment you send a message to someone.
You can set that from `Settings --> Privacy and Security --> Last Seen --> Nobody`

A more detailed explanation, from [Telegram F.A.Q](https://telegram.org/faq):

> ### [Can I hide my 'last seen' time?](https://telegram.org/faq#q-can-i-hide-my-last-seen-time)
>
> You can choose who sees this info in [Privacy and Security](https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-revolution) settings.
>
> Remember that you won‘t see Last Seen timestamps for people with whom you don’t share your own. You will, however, see an approximate last seen value. This keeps stalkers away but makes it possible to understand whether a person is reachable over Telegram. There are four possible approximate values:
>
> - **Last seen recently** — covers anything between 1 second and 2-3 days
> - **Last seen within a week** — between 2-3 and seven days
> - **Last seen within a month** — between 6-7 days and a month
> - **Last seen a long time ago** — more than a month (this is also always shown to blocked users)
>
> ### [Who can see me 'online'?](https://telegram.org/faq#q-who-can-see-me-online)
>
> The [last seen](https://telegram.org/faq#q-can-i-hide-my-last-seen-time) rules apply to your online status as well. People can only see you online if you're sharing your last seen status with them. There is one exception to this: people will be able to see you online for a brief period when you send them a message in a one-on-one chat or in a group where you both are members.

#### App screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is not hiding "online" when you get your app focused

Answer (score 0):

Settings - Privacy and security - Last seen.